# Faster coding than using for loop

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose I have the following data frame

```
set.seed(36)    

n <- 300

dat <- data.frame(x = round(runif(n,0,200)), y =  round(runif(n, 0, 500)))
d <- dat[order(dat$y),]
```

For each value of `d$y<=300`, I have to create a variable `res` in which the numerator is the sum of the indicator `(d$x <= d$y[i])` and the denominator is the sum of the indicator `(d$y >= d$y[i])`. I have written the codes in `for loop`:

```
res <- NULL

for( i in seq_len(sum(d$y<=300)) ){

    numerator   <- sum(d$x <= d$y[i])
    denominator <- sum(d$y >= d$y[i])

    res[i] <- numerator / denominator
 }
```

But my concern is when the number of observations of `x` and `y` is large, that is, the number of rows of the data frame increases, the `for loop` will work slowly. Additionally, if I simulate data 1000 times and each time run the `for loop`, the program will be inefficient.

What can be the more efficient solution of the code?

Comment: You could preallocate `res` and change the denominator to `nrow(d) - i + 1` since you sorted the data.frame

Comment: use `set.seed()` when generating random numbers in your question; so you can test accurately whether the answers are correct.

Comment: @SymbolixAU Thanks, I have edited my question.

Comment: You want to make the comparison against `y[1]`, `y[2]`, ..., even if these particular values are greater than 300?

Comment: @MatthewLundberg May be you asked this from `(d$y >= d$y[i])`. Yes. The process is correct.  And the code also giving correct result. But not efficient.

Comment: @Leaf, please let me know if my answer (i) worked, and (ii) is faster.

Comment: @d.b yes, you're answer with `n=10` matches. Let me study on it. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This depends on `d` already being sorted as it is:

```
# example data
set.seed(36)    
n <- 1e5
dat <- data.frame(x = round(runif(n,0,200)), y =  round(runif(n, 0, 500)))
d <- dat[order(dat$y),]
```

My suggestion (thanks to @alexis_laz for the denominator):

```
system.time(res3 <- {
  xs <- sort(d$x)                                 # sorted x
  yt <- d$y[d$y <= 300]                           # truncated y

  num = findInterval(yt, xs)
  den = length(d$y) - match(yt, d$y) + 1L

  num/den
})
#    user  system elapsed 
#       0       0       0
```

OP's approach:

```
system.time(res <- {
  res <- NULL
  for( i in seq_len(sum(d$y<=300)) ){
    numerator   <- sum(d$x <= d$y[i])
    denominator <- sum(d$y >= d$y[i])
    res[i] <- numerator / denominator
  }
  res
})
#    user  system elapsed 
#   50.77    1.13   52.10 

# verify it matched
all.equal(res,res3) # TRUE
```

@d.b's approach:

```
system.time(res2 <- {
  numerator = rowSums(outer(d$y, d$x, ">="))
  denominator = rowSums(outer(d$y, d$y, "<="))
  res2 = numerator/denominator

  res2 = res2[d$y <= 300]
  res2
})
# Error: cannot allocate vector of size 74.5 Gb

# ^ This error is common when using outer() on large-ish problems
```

**Vectorization.** Generally, tasks are faster in R if they can be vectorized. The key functions related to ordered vectors have confusing names (`findInterval`, `sort`, `order` and `cut`), but fortunately they all work on vectors.

**Continuous vs discrete**. The `match` above should be a fast way to compute the denominator whether the data is continuous or has mass points / repeating values. If the data is continuous (and so has no repeats), the denominator can just be `seq(length(xs), length = length(yt), by=-1)`. If it is fully discrete and has a lot of repetition (like the example here), there might be some way to make that faster as well, maybe like one of these:

```
 den2 <- inverse.rle(with(rle(yt), list(
    values = length(xs) - length(yt) +  rev(cumsum(rev(lengths))), 
    lengths = lengths)))

 tab  <- unname(table(yt))
 den3 <- rep(rev(cumsum(rev(tab))) + length(xs) - length(yt), tab)

 # verify
 all.equal(den,den2) # TRUE
 all.equal(den,den3) # TRUE
```

`findInterval` will still work for the numerator for continuous data. It's not ideal for the repeated-values case considered here I guess (since we're redundantly finding the interval for many repeated `yt` values). Similar ideas for speeding that up likely apply.

**Other options.** As @chinsoon suggested, the data.table package might be a good fit if `findInterval` is too slow, since it has a lot of features focused on sorted data, but it's not obvious to me how to apply it here.

Comment: Not sure I'm missing something but "left.open = TRUE" can be used to overcome the repeated values -- i.e. `length(d$y) - findInterval(yt, d$y, left.open = TRUE)` seems correct as `den`.

Comment: (sorry; couldn't edit above) `length(d$y) - match(yt, d$y) + 1L` seems to be a substitute of the previous `findInterval`

Comment: @alexis_laz Thanks, I'll add that. I'm thinking that finding the match for each element is somewhat redundant (since that `match` will do it for every element of yt even though it's repeating). Maybe... `tab <- unname(table(yt)); den2 <- rep(rev(cumsum(rev(tab))) + length(xs) - length(yt), tab)`?

Comment: Okay, added alexis' way to the main answer, since it's more elegant and also faster (to the point where the benchmark has reached zero on my comp).

Comment: I thought that `match`'s lookup (after hashing `d$y`) would be more efficient from `findInterval`'s search, so that a repeated lookup (which, basically, translates to simply accsessing) would be of small cost relatively to `length(yt)`. TBH, I tried avoiding `match` with a simple integer lookup like `{ h = integer(max(d$y) + 1); h[rev(d$y) + 1L] = length(d$y):1; h[yt + 1L] }` (== `match(yt, d$y)`) but it showed no significant efficiency to outweigh its complexity (compared to `match`)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of running loop, generate all the numerator and denominator at once. This also allows you to keep track of which `res` is associated with which `x` and `y`. Later, you can keep only the ones you want.

You can use `outer` for element wise comparison between vectors.

```
numerator = rowSums(outer(d$y, d$x, ">=")) #Compare all y against all x
denominator = rowSums(outer(d$y, d$y, "<=")) #Compare all y against itself
res2 = numerator/denominator #Obtain 'res' for all rows
#I would first 'cbind' res2 to d and only then remove the ones for 'y <=300'

res2 = res2[d$y <= 300] #Keep only those 'res' that you want
```

Since this is using `rowSums`, this should be faster.

Comment: Is this faster?

Comment: My sample size is not as much large as 100000. Your method is also working there. Thanks (and +1).